# Can’t find pause function in this audio plugin

Tags: jquery, audio

I’m trying this audio music player.
https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Minimal-jQuery-Cross-platform-Audio-Player-MINImusic-Player.html

I’m trying to pause the audio by an click event other than it’s native pause button but I can’t find it’s pause function and don’t know how to play with pause and play function.

If anyone can help me from this community I would appreciate it.

Gratitude in advance.

Comment: The jqueryscript.net site is horrendous. I'd suggest looking on the library's actual page: https://github.com/codovate/MINImusic-Player. It looks like they don't expose any methods via the library to achieve what you need, but you should be able to pause the default audio control: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/pause

Comment: With due respect I want to ask something that when I hit on native pause/play button there must be some piece of code that executes? Now I want to execute that piece of code other than those native buttons. Actually I do need that in an another click event.